# Closure error in Gradle DSL with external dependencies definition

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my gradle files I have externalized all dependency definitions to file `buildsystem/dependencies.gradle`:

```
ext {
  //Android
  androidBuildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
  androidMinSdkVersion = 21
  androidTargetSdkVersion = 23
  androidCompileSdkVersion = 23

  //View libraries
  appcompatVersion = '23.1.1'
  designVersion = '23.1.1'
  //... other dependencies

  //Analytics
  crashlyticsAnswersVersion = '1.3.6'
  crashlyticsCrashlyticsVersion = '2.5.5'

  presentationDependencies = [
        appcompat:            "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompatVersion}",
        design:               "com.android.support:design:${designVersion}",
        //... other
        answer:               "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:${crashlyticsAnswersVersion}@aar",
        crashlytics:          "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsCrashlyticsVersion}@aar",
  ]
}
```

Then, in my `app/build.gradle` file I am using this definition in dependency block:

```
dependencies {
  def presentationDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationDependencies
  def presentationTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.presentationTestDependencies

  compile presentationDependencies.appcompat
  compile presentationDependencies.design

  compile presentationDependencies.answer {
      transitive = true;
  }
  compile presentationDependencies.crashlytics {
      transitive = true;
  }

  //compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6@aar') {
  //    transitive = true;
  //}
  //compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
  //    transitive = true;
  //}

  testCompile presentationTestDependencies.junit
}
```

When Crashlytics dependencies are defined in regular way (commented lines) - compilation pass.
With my configuration, I got an error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.answer() is applicable for argument types:  
(build_3csgketz6zwk5p72to2csf0e$_run_closure3$_closure8) values:
[build_3csgketz6zwk5p72to2csf0e$_run_closure3$_closure8@54bfd47]
Possible solutions: any(), inspect(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

How can I define it? I know, that problem is with closure contains `transitive` field. But I have no idea, what will be the correct way to configure it.

Comment: Try to use `compile (presentationDependencies.answer) {
      transitive = true;
  }`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti - so easy.... Works. I did not see lack of brackets. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Gabriele Mariotti.

There was lack of brackets in

```
 compile (presentationDependencies.crashlytics) {
  transitive = true;
 }
```